# jQuery: show the right part of the string in a second after page loads

Tags: jquery, html, css, string, fadeout

I want to display the part of the string in the first second on the page and the whole string in a second (1000ms).

Example1:
the page loaded:

```
2+2
```

in a second:

```
2+2=4 (=4 added, 2+2 is not moved)
```

Example2:

14+10

in a second:

```
14+10=24 (=24 added, 14+10 is not moved)
```

I would prefer a jQuery solution, but I'm curious if it is possible to do it for any string so that:

1) the string could have different length, the math equation "=" is a kind of delimiter. ("=" is the first of the right part of the string that is not displayed when the page just loaded)

2) the string doesn't contain an additional  or any other html tags that help to manipulate visibility/fadeOut effects for the right part of the string.

Comment: Have you tried to solve this yourself?  What approach did you take, and why didn't it work?

Comment: So will the numbers be set as integers? `var number = 2+2;` or strings? `var number = '2+2';` i'm slightly confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method to get everything before the `=` character and then use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to replace it with the full string after 1 second as follows:

```
// The Equation String
var s = '2 + 2 = 4';

// Split the String at the `=` Character
var splitString = s.split('=');

// Add the First Part of the String to the `div`
$('#answer').text(splitString[0]);

// Wait 1 Second and Show the Whole String
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#answer').text(s);
}, 1000);
```

This will work with any equation that is a string and has the `=` character as a delimiter.

Here is a [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gw44d/).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
var firstPart = "2+2",
    secondPart = "=4";

$("#container").append(firstPart);
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#container").append(secondPart);
}, 1000);
```

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/kQM2w/

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways to go about this, here's one:

```
<p class="foo">2 + 2</p>

<script>
window.setTimeout(function(){
    var result = eval($('.foo').html());
    $('.foo').append(' = ' + result);
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful for you

html:

```
<span id="eq">2+8</span><!-- you can plce here any equation like (16-7)-->
```

jquery:

```
$(function(){
var ans = '='+eval($("#eq").html());

    setTimeout(function(){
    $('#eq').html($("#eq").html()+ans);
    }, 1000);


})
```

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FyaYK/)

Answer (score 1):

I realized you said you are ok with using jQuery but just for fun I decided to put something together that is just pure javascript. I did this in the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U6tVL/2/. The key here is using css classes to show hide the elements (as follow):

```
    var original = document.getElementById("math_original");
    original.className = original.className + " hidden";
```

In order to add a nice fade/show animation to the script you would need to use css animations (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp). Anyways, I hope you find this answer interesting!

Comment: I'm all for pure JavaScript, but why when op said they'd *prefer* a jQuery solution?

Comment: To make it slower for fun!

Comment: Yes, of course, pure JS is fine as well. Thank you for your help.

Comment: ...there was a fair bit of sarcasm in my previous statement : )